# Ghidra scripting: get indirect operand address

Tags: ghidra, script

I tried several hours to find a way to get the operand address which is displayed in the ghidra listing, but without success:

[image: indirect operand address]

I know at least that the OperandType is "Address".

```
import ghidra.program.model.lang.OperandType;

int ot1 = ins1.getOperandType(1);
boolean indirect1 = OperandType.isAddress(ot1); 
                // --> result is true
```

The `op_rep = ins1.getDefaultOperandRepresentation(1)` is of course `[a0]-0x38d8` but I want the resolved reference / address DAT_d0006b78, or with the next instruction, the address of the symbol in the first operand, the address of ACCI_trqDes.

If I use `currentProgram.getAddressFactory().getAddress(op_rep)` the resulting address is null.

I tried it also via `PcodeOp[] pc = ins1.getPcode(opIndex);` but I was much too stupid to understand it.

How can I get this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with the code/data references related API. See the code below (not checked too much, but runs on my last project, in python):

```py
# These imports are accessible when you run the script inside Ghidra
from ghidra.program.model.listing import CodeUnit
from ghidra.program.model.symbol import RefType
from ghidra.program.database import ProgramDB
from ghidra.program.flatapi import FlatProgramAPI

# Mimic getting the current program (In Ghidra's Script Manager, currentProgram is globally available)
state = getState()  # Assume getState() returns the current program state
currentProgram = state.getCurrentProgram()

# Define FlatProgramAPI object for more convenient function calls
flat_api = FlatProgramAPI(currentProgram)

def getReferencesFrom(address):
    return flat_api.getReferencesFrom(address)

def find_data_references_from_address(source_address):
    # Convert the source_address parameter to a Ghidra Address object
    source_addr = currentProgram.getAddressFactory().getAddress(source_address)
        
    # Initialize an empty list to store the referred addresses
    referred_addresses = []
        
    # Get the references from the source address
    references = getReferencesFrom(source_addr)
        
    # Loop through the references to find data references
    for ref in references:
        # Determine the type of the reference
        ref_type = ref.getReferenceType()
            
        # Check if it's a data reference
        if ref_type.isData():
            # Get the address of the code unit that is referred by the source address
            to_addr = ref.getToAddress()
                
            # Add the referred address to our list
            referred_addresses.append(str(to_addr))

    return referred_addresses

# Example usage:
source_address = "0x11390"  # Replace with the source address you're interested in
result = find_data_references_from_address(source_address)
print("Addresses referred to by {}: {}".format(source_address, result))
```

References to Ghidra API documentation may be found [here](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/index.html).

Java variant of the same script with small addition that determines if it is read/write or read+write reference:

```java
import ghidra.app.script.GhidraScript;
import ghidra.program.model.address.Address;
import ghidra.program.model.listing.Program;
import ghidra.program.model.symbol.Reference;
import ghidra.program.model.symbol.ReferenceManager;
import ghidra.program.model.symbol.RefType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindDataReferences extends GhidraScript {

    public List<String> findDataReferencesFromAddress(Program program, String sourceAddress) throws Exception {
        List<String> referredAddresses = new ArrayList<>();

        Address sourceAddr = program.getAddressFactory().getAddress(sourceAddress);
        ReferenceManager refManager = program.getReferenceManager();

        Reference[] references = refManager.getReferencesFrom(sourceAddr);

        for (Reference ref : references) {
            RefType refType = ref.getReferenceType();
            
            String typeDescription = "";
            if (refType.isRead() && refType.isWrite()) {
                typeDescription = "read/write";
            } else if (refType.isRead()) {
                typeDescription = "read";
            } else if (refType.isWrite()) {
                typeDescription = "write";
            }

            if (!typeDescription.isEmpty()) {
                Address toAddr = ref.getToAddress();
                referredAddresses.add(String.format("%s (%s)", toAddr.toString(), typeDescription));
            }
        }

        return referredAddresses;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        String sourceAddress = "0x113e8"; // Replace this with your source address

        List<String> result = findDataReferencesFromAddress(currentProgram, sourceAddress);
        println("Addresses referred to by " + sourceAddress + ": " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you approach it from reverse direction. This works nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   14098c632 48 89 44 24 28            MOV      qword ptr [RSP + local_40],RAX=>KiSchedulerApc
```

for a line like above you want the operand Representation?

you mean something like this

```
>>> currentLocation
OperandFieldLocation@14098c632, refAddr=1402fa5b0, row=0, col=1, charOffset=12, OpRep = RAX=>KiSchedulerApc, subOpIndex = 0, VariableOffset = null
>>> currentLocation.getOperandRepresentation()
u'RAX=>KiSchedulerApc'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted the address referenced, which is shown in the ghidra listing in the form of e.g.  "=> DAT_d0006b78".